# Does Java regex optimize this specific case?

Tags: java, regex

I wonder how does regex work, my particular regex has an element that looks like this:

`(word1|word2|wordn......)`

The numbers of words is big **several hundreds**.
I wonder if the regex engine is just testing the words one by one or if it optimizes the search and it what way.
Any pointer to good documentation will be good.

Comment: [There](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html?page=2) it says : _Beware of alternation. Regular expressions like "(X|Y|Z)" have a reputation for being slow, so watch out for them_

Comment: **[...] instead of "(abcd|abef)" use "ab(cd|ef)" [...]"* -- This is the most trivial form of optimization, and I would be very surprised if the Java regex engine didn't perform this.

Comment: @aioobe not very usefull, with several hundreds of words how do you think I can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several hundred words, you need to beware of the ordering of the words in the regex. The regex engine looks for the words **from left to right**.
If you test the word `setValue` against the alternation `set|setValue`, it will match only the 3 letters comprising "set", and not the whole string.

See this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (from www.regular-expressions.info) for the full explanation.

I don't think that the regex engine truly optimizes alternations (i.e., analyzing common prefixes and building nfa accordingly). Therefore, with so many words, I don't think it will be an optimization.

Aside from re-ordering the words, you can also try adding word or line boundary after the alternation, e.g. `(set|setValue)$`, but I suspect that the regex engine will do a lot of backtracking so it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I presume the engine still test each word letter by letter and will backtrack as soon as a letter differs right?

Comment: I want a benchmark of this (handoptimized against naive  regex).

Comment: Yes, it will backtrack letter by letter, but still there can be tons of backtracking with hundreds of words

Answer (score 1):

If it seems to you that the RE engine is the bottleneck in such search, you could easily construct a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and check for containment.

Comment: Very interesting, I might try this one. Any Java implementation that you know of ? Or I may use hash map implementation described in your link.

Comment: For the record you can find an interesting Java implementation of TRIE [here](https://github.com/rkapsi/simple-patricia-trie#readme)